# listen for jQuery load event for a certain page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to add some functionality to my posts/new page when it loads, using jQuery. Is it possible to specifically listen to the jQuery page load event for any particular page?

Comment: There is no "jQuery page load event". jQuery adds a listener that waits for a DOM ready (or similar) event to occur, then does something, falling back to the load event if it doesn't get called sooner. See bfavaretto's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
if($("#elementId").length > 0){
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });
}
```

You can also use it is same as ready method.

```
$(function(){

});
```

Comment: I am aware of this, and this is for a general page load. I am looking to execute something only for a specific URL, or say, if the page contains an element with a specific id

Comment: Sweet. That works. Could you help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005751/access-session-variable-using-jquery)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

OR simply:

```
$(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: I am aware of this, and this is for a general page load. I am looking to execute something only for a specific URL, or say, if the page contains an element with a specific id.

Comment: Inside that, check if the element exists with `$('#yourid').length`